# Generic xml stream writer to oracle clob

Tags: .net

My question is do we have any libraries with similar implementation to stream huge xml async and store to oracle clob column?
Trying to wirte generic xml stream read and write to oracle xml clob

I have searched a lot but I don't see any library which can do this, still need some improvements to the code so that it updates clob column instead of inserting new record for each read.

```
static async Task Main()
{
    const string connectionString = "<your connection string>";
    const string tableName = "<your table name>";
    const int chunkSize = 100000;

    using var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    using var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
    using var command = connection.CreateCommand();
    command.Transaction = transaction;
    command.CommandText = $"INSERT INTO {tableName} (xml_clob) VALUES (:clob)";
    var parameter = new OracleParameter("clob", OracleDbType.Clob);

    const string filePath = "large-file.xml";
    using var reader = XmlReader.Create(filePath);
    var semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(50);

    var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
    var settings = new XmlWriterSettings
    {
        Indent = true,
        IndentChars = "    "
    };

    while (await reader.ReadAsync())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
            case XmlNodeType.Element:
                using var ms = new MemoryStream();
                using var writer = XmlWriter.Create(ms, settings);
                writer.WriteStartElement(reader.Name);
                if (reader.HasAttributes)
                {
                    while (reader.MoveToNextAttribute())
                    {
                        writer.WriteAttributeString(reader.Name, reader.Value);
                    }

                    reader.MoveToElement();
                }
                writer.Flush();
                ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                parameter.Value = new OracleClob(connection, true);
                using var clobWriter = new StreamWriter(parameter.Value, Encoding.Unicode);
                await ms.CopyToAsync(clobWriter.BaseStream);
                await clobWriter.FlushAsync();
                var task = command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                tasks.Add(task);
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                break;

            case XmlNodeType.Text:
                using var ms2 = new MemoryStream();
                using var writer2 = XmlWriter.Create(ms2);
                while (!reader.EOF)
                {
                    char[] buffer = new char[chunkSize];
                    int charsRead = await reader.ReadValueChunkAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                    if (charsRead == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    await writer2.WriteCharsAsync(buffer, 0, charsRead);
                }

                writer2.Flush();
                ms2.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                parameter.Value = new OracleClob(connection, true);
                using var clobWriter2 = new StreamWriter(parameter.Value, Encoding.Unicode);
                await ms2.CopyToAsync(clobWriter2.BaseStream);
                await clobWriter2.FlushAsync();
                var task2 = command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                tasks.Add(task2);
                break;
        }
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished processing XML file '{filePath}'");
}
```

Also was planning this approach to make it right quicker

```
using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public async Task SaveFileToOracleClobParallel(string filePath, string connectionString)
{
    const int bufferSize = 81920; // 80KB buffer size
    const int maxDegreeOfParallelism = 4; // maximum number of tasks to run in parallel

    try
    {
        using (var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString))
        {
            await connection.OpenAsync();

            using (var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction())
            using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.Transaction = transaction;
                command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO MyTable (MyClobColumn) VALUES (:clob)";

                using (var clob = new OracleClob(connection))
                {
                    await clob.OpenAsync(OracleDbType.Clob, System.Data.ConnectionState.Open);

                    var tasks = new List<Task>();

                    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, bufferSize, FileOptions.SequentialScan))
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < maxDegreeOfParallelism; i++)
                        {
                            tasks.Add(ReadAndWriteChunkAsync(stream, clob, bufferSize));
                        }

                        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
                    }

                    await clob.CloseAsync();
                    command.Parameters.Add(new OracleParameter("clob", OracleDbType.Clob) { Value = clob });

                    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                    await transaction.CommitAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
        // Handle the exception as appropriate
    }
}

private async Task ReadAndWriteChunkAsync(Stream stream, OracleClob clob, int bufferSize)
{
    var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
    int bytesRead;

    while ((bytesRead = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
    {
        await clob.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the file straight through using `CopyToAsync`

```cs
static async Task Main()
{
    const string connectionString = "<your connection string>";
    const string query = "INSERT INTO <your table name> (xml_clob) VALUES (:clob)"

    await using var connection = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
    await connection.OpenAsync();
    using var command = new OracleCommand(query, connection, transaction);
    var parameter = new OracleParameter(":clob", OracleDbType.Clob).Value = new OracleClob(connection, true);

    const string filePath = "large-file.xml";
    await using var file = File.Open(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    await ms.CopyToAsync(parameter.Value);
    await clobWriter.FlushAsync();
    await command.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    Console.WriteLine($"Finished processing XML file '{filePath}'");
}
```

Comment: Hi thank you, I tried earlier this approach earlier but this doesn't guarantee that xml is is formed correct and not malformed.. is there way to check that before saving directly? That's when I had to write all that code :)

Comment: Probably easier to just read the file twice, once to validate and again to send it to Oracle

Comment: Ok let me try that, thank you.